# What fraction of Davos participants are billionaires (and not corporations or political leaders) and who decides which ones can go?

Tags: international-relations, economy, international, financial-crisis, finance

The Late Show with Stephen Colbert's May 21, 2022 [Crypto Celebs Silent As Market Melts Down | Billionaires Get Ready To Trip At Davos](https://youtu.be/4c_67Pvg2jA?t=128) cites Business Insider's August 27, 2020 (updated) [Davos 2021 is postponed — here's what you need to know about the invitation-only conference that brings billionaires together with business and political leaders at a Swiss ski resort](https://www.businessinsider.com/what-is-davos-world-economic-forum-conference-2020-1) (which in turn cites CBS News' January 19, 2018 [What is Davos?](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/what-is-davos/)) and Entrepreneur's May 16, 2022 [Who Gets to Attend Davos? Everything You Need to Know About the Notoriously Difficult-to-Get-Into Conference](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/427091)

The Business Insider quote that Colbert highlights is:

> ...conference that brings billionaires together with business and political leaders at a Swiss ski resort...

and that of Entrepreneurs':

> Participants address critical concerns including wealth management, climate change...and...more.

**Question:** What fraction of Davos participants are billionaires (and not corporations or political leaders) and who decides which ones can go?

I understand there could be some overlap; I'm only asking about participants who's only qualifications are the amount of money they have and control.

From Wikipedia's [World Economic Forum; Annual meeting in Davos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Economic_Forum#Annual_meeting_in_Davos):

> At the 2018 annual meeting, more than 3,000 participants from nearly 110 countries participated in over 400 sessions. Participation included more than 340 public figures, including more than 70 heads of state and government and 45 heads of international organizations; 230 media representatives and almost 40 cultural leaders were represented.

Comment: international-relations tag is used because "May also be used for questions relating to international organisations" and the [World Economic Forum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Economic_Forum)  is one.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the second part of your question – the ["Entrepreneur" article](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/427091) that you reference explicitly states that "Davos is an invitation-only event", so it's clearly the World Economic Forum who decides who will be invited to the meeting.

Comment: @Schmuddi I can change it to "who exactly" or "how" if you like, but I don't see how an organization answers to "who". However if we try it: "Who decides what features will be on the next iPhone?" the tautological answer "Apple decides." would not be wrong but it would be profoundly uninformative and unwelcome. So "Who is the World Economic Forum?" Is it just the "1,000 member companies" or do individual billionaire members vote for themselves and their friends as well? Is it *effectively* the largest companies, or do the largest company and the lowliest billionaire have equal say?

Answer (score 1):

There are globally around 2,100 billionaires which Oxfam says have more wealth than 4.6 billion ordinary people on this planet.

Davos usually plans for around 2,000 delegates. Apparently this year the heads of major banks - like Goldman Sachs - aren't going and neither are many Russian oligarchs for obvious reasons. But there are expected to be around 90 billionaires. So this works out to *roughly* 4.5%.

Recently, a group of around a hundred millionaires and billionaires, including a Disney Heiress, have called out global leaders to tax the wealthy more highly.

Note, data is from a Bloomberg Article.

Comment: Please provide a source for all claims in your answer.

Comment: @Stuart F: Did you not see the last sentence where I noted that the info was taken from Bloomberg???!!!

Comment: ...Is [this article](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-05-23/davos-forum-is-back-with-less-billionaire-starpower-and-no-snow) the one you're citing? If so, you should probably include a link to it – and/or include other info about the specific source, such as the headline of the article. ([Here's a Google-cache version of the link, without the paywall.](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:yKo4LTH_5z8J:https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-05-23/davos-forum-is-back-with-less-billionaire-starpower-and-no-snow&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us))

Comment: @V2Blast it looks like the author won't be able to respond at the moment nor benefit from bounty, but with that link added to the question I feel fine awarding it anyway so the full +100 displays for future readers. There's about 23 hours + a 24 hour grace period left on the bounty and I'll keep an eye out for further answers, but if none are found perhaps you can add your link to the question (I can see it un-paywalled or some reason) or I can.